# Mule custom connector as a Message source

Tags: mule, connector

Can we write a Mule custom connector which can act as a Message Source?

I know we can write a connector using which a flow can integrate with the relevant system/endpoint. Can any please tell me if I can write a connector which act as a Message Source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, see here: it has an example of how it's done in the Salesforce connector for the Streaming API Message Source: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Creating+Message+Sources

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a connector which is like HTTP Listener, but custom connector.

Comment: yes, thats how you do it using a custom connector @Source using the Devkit. If you want to see the http:listener though then the source is available n Github: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.x/modules/http/src/main/java/org/mule/module/http